# Convert html file to pdf on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoa, pdf, applescript

I am looking to convert an html file to a pdf without any 3rd party utilities. I am not thrilled with the output from cupsfilter and I don't want to script a browser. This AppleScript / Ruby script used PDFKit to resave a pdf (to get around an InDesign problem).  Is there any way of modifying it to accept an html file as input? Any other solutions are welcome too!

```
on pdf_resave(infile, outfile)
    set rb to "require 'osx/cocoa'
OSX.require_framework 'PDFKit'
include OSX

raise ArgumentError, %Q[Usage: $0 <input pdf> <output pdf>] unless ARGV.length == 2
infile, outfile = ARGV
url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(infile)
pdf = PDFDocument.alloc.initWithURL(url)
pdf.writeToFile(outfile)"

    do shell script "/usr/bin/ruby -e " & rb's quoted form & " " & infile's quoted form & " " & outfile's quoted form
end pdf_resave
```

Comment: why is your input pdf? I thought you wanted to convert HTML? re: `ArgumentError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using the webkit HTML to pdf library, https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf.

You can just call the binary from within Ruby.

Install it with:

```
brew install wkhtmltopdf
```

You can package it up into a bundle with the Ruby script if deployment/dependency concerns are an issue. You'd simply add a checkout and compile stage to the install script (thus avoiding the need to install `brew`.) - you can package a pre-made binary this way too, as long as you test it on the target platforms (I'd suggest 10.6 up and you're safe).

For more info on making a `.pkg` install bundle see this [succinct  guide](http://www.osxgnu.org/info/osxpackages.html).

That's all overkill though, because, as far as I can see at least, `wkhtmltopdf` does the job for you from start to finish, other than feeding it a batch of html files, in which case wrap it in a shell script, and stop mucking about ;)

Comment: That is what I found as well. The user did not want to install any 3rd party extras.

Comment: That's purely from ignorance, on the user's part, there's no way to handle PDFs without a library. (Unless they're willing to invest **serious $$$** to develop an in house one, this I strongly doubt though) - don't let idiotic user requests hamper you, you need to find a way to skirt around their assertions and politely explain to them that this is just how it has to be done.  It's a bit like telling an electrician you don't want any fuses, sure it'll work, but at what cost! A large part of the job is explaining to people who are wilfully ignorant, without them feeling stupid at the end of it.

Comment: @adayzdone - by the way, if installing `brew` will get in the way, see my updated answer, you can just checkout (or include the wkhtmltopdf source) into the install bundle and compile it as part of the install process. - assuming you need to add it to multiple machines.  Alternatively you could just package the binary on it's own as long as it works on your target machines, you could taget a binary compilation at 10.7 (or 10.6) and use it "everywhere" ie. all Lion, Mt Lion and (Snow Leopard) boxes.